# Status of jQuery TestSwarm?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testswarm

I hope You are more 'on the ball' than I am.

I remember getting news on the **Mozilla labs TestSwarm** (now jQuery TestSwarm) some time ago. It had active users then, but it was not more than 10 per a single browser+OS configuration.

I went there today expecting it to be far better and it turns out that there are NO active testing environments. Moreover, when I tried to view the http://testswarm.com service:

> Invalid query: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` once in every two or three queries.

Is this project dead? Are there any similiar community projects for JS testing that I could not only take part in, but use for my code? Or do I have to test JS myself?

Comment: It lookED interesting. The numbers in the red are counts of browsers present on the system. It used to be about 10 each...

Comment: There's still github activity for the project, and from what I understand, the red count is for currently present browsers, but the test suite will run as different users sign on and off. Given the low level of activity, you would expect it to take a while to run all the browsers, but it should happen eventually.

Comment: Yet still it used to be crowdy when I visited it some months ago. And I can't get it to run tests on me becouse of that error.

Comment: The last commits on http://github.com/jeresig/testswarm/ were back at the end of March. I'd be suprised if it died, as it was created by John Resig (jQuery creator) and it would be very useful for jQuery. I guess it's just been put on the back burner for a while.

I don't know of any similar testing communities, but TestSwarm is on GitHub, so you could easily fork it and create your own.

Comment: testswarm.com seems to have been closed in favor of swarm.jquery.org (and potentially other "swarms" elsewhere)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At FOWA Miami in February (2010) I asked John Resig about it and his answer was like this (not exact words but that's what I remember of it): Still very much high in his plans since the next steps were to get jQuery Core support on mobile really solid and part of achieving this goal will be the need to automate testing on various platforms as much as possible which is what test swarm is about.

Comment: So it's just about people not rushing to participate. Thanks for finding out.

Answer (score 19):

The following website is still live. 
http://swarm.jquery.org/

(The link on that site is old at the moment I'm writing this.)
And if you want the code: 
https://github.com/jquery/testswarm

Comment: Did you see the date on my question?

Comment: Yeah, I did. But when i started searching this stackoverflow article was one of the results. So if someone else starts searching: I'm presenting a faster result. And also removing doubts that the project is (currently) dead.

Comment: Yep, a year later and here I am :)

Comment: Ditto =) There's a necromancer badge for a reason. +1's @knowledge_is_power

Answer (score 4):

The project is still alive. John last committed around April 13, 2011. The unit tests for jQuery core and QUnit both make use of the swarm and are updated at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Microsoft either forked the code or recreated the project.

Check out [BrowserSwarm](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/09/26/introducing-browserswarm-spend-less-time-testing-your-next-javascript-project.aspx)

Another recent alternative seems to be [CodeSwarm](http://codeswarm.com/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @FirstZero I'm pretty sure the title includes "Any equivalents?".... Therefore it does provide an alternative at which the author requested.